# get posts by their tags in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am showing each post tags in my blade now I want make some sort of search for my tags, (take image below as sample)

[image: screen 1]

I want when users clicks on `laravel` tag result of every post with laravel tag show to them.

## Question

1. How should I make that function?

## Code

`posts model`

```php
public function tags(){
   return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class);
}
```

`tags model`

```php
public function posts(){
   return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class);
}
```

Comment: Is `Tag::find($id)->posts` not working?

Comment: how should i pass that?

Comment: You have to share more of your code (controller, view). Does clicking on a tag open a new page?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir ok i get them now, but what if i want use tag `title` in my url instead of `id`? so in my url will be like `site/tag-search/laravel` instead of `site/tag-search/1`

Comment: Is the title unique? You could also combine `id` and `title`: `site/tag-search/laravel/1`

Comment: yes title is unique, but my question is when i pass title instead of id to my controller, how do i retrieve the id of it so I can find that id in my posts? (you know we actually will search by tag id, just show title in url instead)

Comment: You can use `Tag::where('title', $title)->first()`. Or [`getRouteKeyName()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-model-binding) if you use route model binding.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir thanks man, please share `Tag::find($id)->posts` as answer I'll confirm it.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```php
Post::whereHas('tags', function($query) use ($tag) {
    $query->where('title', $tag);
})->get();
```

Where `$tag` would be your tag title.

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Route model binding example from within `RouteServiceProvider`:

```php
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    Route::patterns([
        'tag_title' => '[a-z]+',
    ]);

    Route::get('posts/{tag_title}', function ($tag_title) {
        return Tag::where('title', $tag_title)->firstOrFail();
    });
}
```

Comment: I'll try it and let you know thanks, just one question should i change `{id}` in my route in order to get tag title in url? If yes what should i add instead?

Comment: It really depends on how you're binding models to the route - I would recommend using `RouteServiceProvider` - you could then bind it explicitly using `title` https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-model-binding

Comment: I've added example of the route model binding.